# Windows Network Path in Mac

Tags: macos, network, windows

I am a newbie at this and I have some issues with a certain network address. The format, in Windows was \folder\folder\folder\file.ext . My Question is, how can I access it using my macbook? Thank you for help

Comment: You'll have to ask you network admin - the path you give does not have enough information (There might be enough info if you could tell what the drive letter was mapped to on the network e.g. what `net use` or the graphic equivalent shows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows a UNC (network path) looks like this:

`\\SERVER\share\path\more_path\file.ext`

The same network path would look like this on the Mac:

`smb://SERVER/share/path/more_path/file.ext`